# open application from url - ios 10

Tags: ios, xcode8, xcode9

I have an applet from which I can download another app,
Through the plist that goes to ipa,
It takes a lot of time from reading to url and by the time I see that the app is starting to drop,
Is there a way that it will not take time to click?

Comment: a lot of time from ...

Comment: example code:NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://.....plist"] ;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];

Answer (score -1):

```
                let appId = "xxx"
            let storeUrl = String(format: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@", arguments: [appId])
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: storeUrl)!)
```

Comment: the app in my store